# The state variable not returning value as expected Flutter

Tags: flutter

I defined a bool variable on the state class. After that in build method I checked the variable to update UI like this.

```
class _CategoryItemState extends State<CategoryItem> {
  var _expanded = true;

....

@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
...

if (_expanded)
  Container(color: blue,
  height: 10),
```

But the container is not showing. If i replaced `if(_expanded)` with `if(true)`, it is working fine. Why this strange behaviour?

This whole widget is an item in ListView.builder(). So If i scroll down some way(and also back to top), there I can find the container's are showing. Please help me, I lost my day behind this problem.

Comment: Have you tried printing _expanded value to make sure? Do you have any initState instructions?

Comment: No code, But I got some clues   about  the problem.. still cannot figure out how to solve. The container shows on first time I hot reload. Then when I update the expanded with setstate, the already builded listview items are not updating. when scroll to new items they are updating fine.

Comment: SetSate not updating the already rendered object, any way to rebuild all listview.builder?